# What is this "as"?

Tags: grammar

With the same energy as I was reading Peter Pan, he was reading Tom Sawyer. From Essay by Sarah D. Smith.

Is this "as" like the same A as B?

but not "with the same energy with which I was readig..."

Why?

Comment: I would take it to mean that he was no less engaged with the book *Tom Sawyer* than I with the book *Peter Pan*.

Comment: Your *the same A as B* doesn't really encapsulate the usage. It's more a matter of *the same A as [the A associated with] B*. So the expanded version of your example is something like *He reads Tom Sawyer with the same energy as [the energy with which] I read Peter Pan*.

Comment: That as is the same as as the other as.

Answer (score 1):

> With the same energy as I was reading Peter Pan, he was reading Tom Sawyer.

This sentence is a bit confusing because the prepositional phrase, the adjunct "*with the same energy as I was reading Peter Pan* has be preposed. It appears at the front of the sentence. A more normal phrase order would be:

- He was reading Tom Sawyer with the same energy as I was reading Peter Pan.

There is some information missing from the comparative clause because it is easy to guess from the main clause. We can reconstruct the sentence like this:

- He was reading Tom Sawyer with the same energy as I was reading Peter Pan [with that energy].

The *as* here is the same preposition that we find in: the same A as B. It usually comes before an equative phrase. This means that '*as*' shows that the thing talked about before *as* and the thing after it are equal.

We can get exactly the same reading for the sentence if we use a relative clause instead of a comparative clause:

- He was reading Tom Sawyer with the same energy with which I was reading Peter Pan.

This time there will be a gap at the end of the clause representing *with which*:

- He was reading Tom Sawyer with the same energy with which I was reading Peter Pan [with it].

Hope this helps!